# Find location of activity in multiwindow mode android

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

I want to know whether my activity is in *upper view* or *bottom view* in the **multi-window** mode.

The reason for this is I'm using a custom `MediaController` in a player activity which gets behind the `NavigationBar`.

Earlier I handled this by adding a bottom margin of the  `NavigationBar`height to the `MediaController` but I *can't* use it in multi-window mode.

When the activity is in upper view of the multi-window mode, I need to remove the bottom margin and when it is in bottom view, I have to provide the bottom margin.

I've tried applying `android:fitsInSystemWindows=true` attribute to the activity layout and media controller layout, but it *didn't* help.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View:getWindowVisibleFrame](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(android.graphics.Rect)) method and check `rect.top`.

Comment: Where do I need to use it?

Comment: when you need to check if you are in multiwindow mode

Comment: I'm able to access getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() for media controller. But Rect.top isn't any variable. And what is this method used for?

Comment: `top` is always 0 when `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`